# MySQL query joining issue

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

```
--Categories--
id, Name

-- Products --
id, name, price

-- productCategories --
id, product_id, category_id
```

i want to get similar products.

for instance. to get similar products by name i wrote

```
SELECT * FROM products 
            where products.name in (select products.name from products
            join productcategories on products.id=productcategories.product_id
            group by products.name having count(*)>1)
```

But i can't get products that are similar by cateogory.
i wrote something like this, but it's wrong

```
 SELECT * FROM products 
                where 
products.name in(select products.name from products join productcategories
                                on products.id=productcategories.product_id
                                join Categories on productcategories.category_id =Categories.id)
```

can u help me, please?

Comment: Your should edit your question with sample data and desired results.  "Similar by" is rather ambiguous.

Comment: Note that id in your 3rd table serves no useful purpose